# Can I return the run time data generated during my test execution from the step definition files to cucumber feature files

Tags: protractor, cucumber, report, node-modules, typescript1.8

I have a scenario where the a policy number get generated randomly in the step definition file, this policy number needs to be displayed in the reports (I m using protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin for reporting). Since the reports are reading the data from Examples keyword in the feature file, I need to return the policy number generated in the step definition file to the feature file

1. My step in Feature File
   When the value "  " is entered in "Policy Number" text field

Examples:
policyNumber   |
               |

2. My code in Step Definition File

   else if(string2=="Policy Number"){
     await browser.wait(waitCondition.visibilityOf(applicationDataEntryPagePE.policyNumberTextBox), 2000).then(async(textboxVisible)=>{
       policyNumber = await string+timestamp.getHours()+timestamp.getMinutes()+timestamp.getMilliseconds();
       await applicationDataEntryPagePE.policyNumberTextBox.sendKeys(policyNumber);
       await console.log("Entered the value "+policyNumber+ " in Policy Number field");
       return policyNumber;
     })
   }

I need to return policyNumber to the Examples value in the Feature file

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution.

Add the `policy number` to the global variable and access it with in step_def directly (simple approach). This will show you the policy number in the result too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @supputuri. I tried this solution, but the data from the global variable is not displayed in the reports